# use other raspberry pi as mysql server

Tags: java, jdbc, raspberry-pi2

I have installed all the correct drivers and packages on my raspberry pi and i can use localhost to send stuff from the raspberry pi to the server on that raspberry pi, but what is the address to send information from one pi to another one with mysql on it, say for instance my ip on the server pi is 192.168.1.11 using jdbc whats the address to connect to it?

Thanks Jonny

Answer (score 1):

MySQL connection strings, at least for Java follow the following structure: `jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:<port>/<dbName>`, thus, assuming that you want to connect to a Database named `foo` running on your server at `192.168.1.11`, you would need to do something like so: `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.11:3306/foo`. This assumes that your MySQL DB is running on the default port of 3306.

You can also specify the user name and password for the account you want to use in your connection string as well (although I wouldn't really recommend it): `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.11:3306/foo?user=userName&password=pass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to it with that IP

You might need to add the user to be able to access the connect from outsite, something like this should work for you.

```
CREATE USER user@* identified by 'PASSWORD';
GRANT ALL ON database.* TO 'user'@'*';
```

**Be carefull that this opens the mysql access from every IP address.**

To only let it be from one specific IP (where 1.2.3.4 is the IP you want access from)

```
CREATE USER user@1.2.3.4 identified by 'PASSWORD';
GRANT ALL ON database.* TO 'user'@'1.2.3.4';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy, you need mysql jdbc url:

```
jdbc:mysql://<server-host>:<port>/<database-name>
```

You have to change:

- `<server-host>` for the **IP** or **hostname** of the pi with mysql
- `<port>` usually `3306`
- `<database-name>`

Also you have to ensure your mysql server is configured to allow remote connections and not only from localhost.